# Unity: How to orient camera along tangent plane to sphere?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, orientation, orbital-mechanics

I have a camera that orbits a globe. While orbiting the globe, the user can click on other objects, which will cause the camera to orbit that object instead. So, from the start, it looks like this.

[image]

After clicking the object, the camera will move to focus on it, but stay at whatever rotation in was in beforehand, like so:

[image]

However, what I would like the camera to do is orient itself to have the globe always at the bottom part of the frame, so as if it's looking along a tangent plane (I think?). Somewhat like this.

[image]

And what the player sees would be akin to this.

[image]

I apologize profusely for my artistic skills.

I went to the Unity documentation and found [Computing Normal Perpendicular Vector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputingNormalPerpendicularVector.html), which I believe is closely related to the problem I'm having.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
Vector3 a = target.position;
Vector3 b = earth.transform.position;
Vector3 c = north.transform.position;
Vector3 side1 = b - a;
Vector3 side2 = c - a;
Vector3 tangent = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);
transform.LookAt(tangent);
```

"target" is the asteroid or whatever object the camera is rotating around. "earth" is the globe, and "north" is a game object centered at the North Pole. This script is attached to the camera. Right now this just makes the camera orient itself in a variety of ways that I can't really identify a pattern for.

Answer (score 0):

[`LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) takes an absolute world position Vector. You are passing in a **direction** Vector returned by [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) which is not quite what you want.

---

I would simply give the Sphere object a `SphereCollider` (if it doesn't have one anyway).

Then on the camera you could have a script using [`Collider.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html) and use the target position as a reference.

This position you can then pass into `LookAt`

something like

```
public Collider sphereCollider;

public void LookAtTarget(Transform target)
{
    var position = sphereCollider.ClosestPoint(target.position);

    transform.LookAt(position);
}
```

This should center the Camera on the point exactly "under" the target object on the Sphere surface thus that the Sphere surface fills half of the screen.

Comment: transform.LookAt(earth.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<SphereCollider>().ClosestPoint(target.position));
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, the orientation of the camera when I click an object is still dependent on what it was beforehand.